# How to identify or calculate the electromagnetic interference (EMI) contribution of components on PCB

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, emc

I am designing a circuit using the Motor Driver IC TB6612FNG. Now I am unaware about how can I calculate the EMI contribution by this IC.
I did add the bypass and decoupling, grounding control, transmission line control, and trace termination matching to achieve the Electromagnetic Compatibility.

My question how do we measure the EMI contributed before and after the addition of the bypass and decoupling, grounding control, transmission line control, and trace termination matching ?

Is there a theoretical way to determine or predict this ?

Does the datasheet provide any related information, if yes where can I find it in the datasheet?

Comment: It is correct that you can predict it with modelling, but the usual way is to build it, enclose it, and have it pre-tested, or rent/borrow your own EMI scope/analyzer.

Answer (score 4):

> My question how do we measure the EMI contributed before and after the addition of the bypass and decoupling, grounding control, transmission line control, and trace termination matching ?

Yes, you could use a Electromagnetic Finite Element (EM FEM) to model the noise on the PCB. ANSYS and Comsol make programs that can simulate noise sources and EMI, one can even import a 3d model and see how a noise source would propagate noise on and off the PCB. However these programs are usually more time consuming to use then actually building and testing a PCB. Because of this I build and test since I have to test prototypes anyway.

> Is there a theoretical way to determine or predict this ?

A good start is this book, (since there is more information on EMC that you request than can be posted in an answer). Chapter 5.2 describes transmission lines.
Chapter 6 describes shielding.

Shielding is probably what you want to do, since if the IC or the PCB is radiating, a shield can help you meet FCC regulations.

Another problem is radiation emitted from cables, ferrites and adding inductance can stop cables from radiating.

[image]

Source: http://www.hottconsultants.com/EMCE_book_files/emce_book.html (no affiliation, except I own the book and think it's great)

Answer (score 3):

This is highly dependent on layout. Loop area of fast transitioning signals, placement location of decoupling, board stack up, etc. affects the effectiveness of EMI mitigating measures significantly. If you have the design laid out, it is possible to estimate parasitics by using the layout tool to measure  distances (to planes, to high frequency traces and leads, loop areas of signals etc).

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa094/sboa094.pdf

This is good read for parasitics.

Comment: I think estimating parasitics by measuring distances may not provide the complete overall EMI contribution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not something in the datasheet, because it fully depends on how you use a component. If you use a motor driver IC to rapidly switch a large inductive motor, it will produce more EMI at higher frequencies than if you slowly switch a small motor, for example.

> Is there a theoretical way to measure this ?

Um, "measurement" is kind of the opposite of "theory"; however, yes, you can get an idea of what your circuit emits by looking at the *spectrum* of what it's likely to emit.

The next step is simulation using an EM simulation tool.

Comment: "measurement" is kind of the opposite of "theory" - By theory what I wanted to say is, if  there is a possible way to calculate the EMI contribution by an equation, which I think should be possible ideally but may be more complex, as everything has an equation. Thanks for the reply. May be I need to spend sometime studying how to use EM Simulation Tool.

Comment: I edited it for your @Ravi

Comment: @P2000 thanks! Yeah, that's why I said "um, …; however:": The spectrum, or the *power spectral density* is a theoretical property of the signals you're emitting. I think that's what we're after here, right?

Comment: @P2000 Thank you for the edit

Answer (score 1):

I've been estimating NEAR_FIELD interference for many years, to implement risk control and predict the code_spread of analog_digital_converter measurements.

The methods of estimating near_field are applicable to EMI/RFI, because

- dI/dT and loop area and distance of magnetic coupllng
- dV/dT and capacitive coupling and victim_node impedance of electric coupling

are applicable to reducing external EMI risks UPFRONT, long before you have a chance to TEST or MEASURE in an EMI lab with those special antennas.

In many cases, simply using a GROUND PLANE is all you need. In any case, if you expect success for radiated EMI or susceptibility (where your circuit can be impaired by external energy), you need to use a GROUND PLANE, without slits.

Without SLITS.

I've guided numerous projects to EMI/RFI success (passed FCC requirements), once the engineers involved were hit with "You failed Emissions. Figure it out." as a priority in their life. Often the only changes were "Your double-sided PCB has a badly chopped-up Ground. Let us greatly improve that, by slightly moving components, to have few or no ground_jumpers needed and instead have wide traces joining these large GND pieces."

Sort of like designing a STEALTH FIGHTER ---- edges of metal are BAD for stealthiness. Avoid edges. Use sheets of metal; they are your friend.

========================================

Decades ago I developed a TV channel 2/3/4 receiver, as accessory for video recorders. The equivalent input Noise Figure was 2dB, which I did not believe, then I realized the PI matching from 75 ohms to the Rin of NE602 provided 12dB improvement of the SNR.

Thus the 2/3/4 receiver was a sensitive broadband RF system.

I decided to try to jam it, to learn about EMI methods, EMI thinking, in PCB planning, positioning, metal_fills, etc.

I had a Philipps NSTC video/RF generator with precision carrier settability. By turning off the modulation, I had a pure_sin RF generator/jammer.

I brought small plates (for Efield injection) and small coils (for Hfield injection) near the PCB, attending to input of NE602 mixer and the MC44301 IF/ALC/synch_demod. I particularly focused on input to MC44301 If Amplifier and the SAW filter just preceeding.

Even at 0 dBm power levels into the plate (EFI) or the coil (HFI), twas very difficult to visually see ANY upset to the demodulated video display (Sony Trinitron).

How could this be? I has 0dBm power levels, attempting to couple onto extremely sensitive 44.75 MHz IF (intermediate frequency) PCB traces.

Let us compute the power level for +20dB SNR, and then compare that to 0dBm from the Philipps NTSC RF generator.

- -174 dBm per rootHertz is the thermal noise floor at room temperature
- 14 dB for input matching (to NE602) and losses
- 20dB for Video IF estimated SNR[yes, this is a POOR VIDEO SNR]
- 67 dB for well_defined bandwidth of the SAW filter

---

- Total = -174 + 14 + 20 + 67 == -73dBm into the SAW

My 2/3/4 PC was 1.5" by 6", not a wavelength by any means. The 2_sided PCB had a un-slitted top_side with few vias (lots of Surface Mount on backside), and a few opening for SurfaceMount ICs.

Yet with 73dB stronger EMI (into a 1cm * 1cm plate held 1 few MilliMeters from the SMT components for Efield injection), only small upset to the Video was apparent. ANd the small coil -- a few milliMeters indiameter --- had no effect at all.

Summary: A SOLID GROUND PLANE (or VDD plane) is your friend, for airborne EMI rejection.